# How do I deploy a virtualized server on a headless machine running 12.04 Server?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

There is so much different information out there about setting up a virtual machine but I'm at a lost where to start. My fundamental question is:

**How do I virtually deploy a web server (complete with a unique set of users) on top of the headless machine that I'm running?**

The things that make my particular system unique (i.e. makes it hard for me to find information via google):

1. Server is wireless.
2. Server doesn't run a GUI.

Most tutorials/howtos assume a wired connection and/or a GUI.

#### What I've Tried

1. I've read documentation for `libvirt`, `qemu`, and `kvm`. I've also seen a number of tutorials that use `ubuntu-vm-builder` or `qemu-img`. I'm just not sure where to start. I'm not sure how to think about the entire stack: I *think* it looks like this: `libvirt` --controls--> `qemu` --controls--> `kvm`. But I'm not sure.
2. I've turned on virtualization through the BIOS on my system.
3. I've installed the `qemu*` and `libvirt*` packages.
4. I've tried to run `qemu-system-x86_64 ubuntu-server-12.04.iso` with the downloaded server ISO. This didn't work.

#### Challenges I haven't found the answers to yet.

1. What are the canonical steps to get a virtualized server running? Do you start with `qemu-img`? Or does the first step begin with `ubuntu-vm-builder`?
2. How do you keep it running every time your physical server boots?
3. One tutorial noted that [you couldn't bridge off of a wireless card.](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bridge#It_doesn.27t_work_with_my_Wireless_card.21) Is this still true today?
4. I don't understand how to edit `/etc/network/interfaces`. I use wlan0 as my primary networking interface so I'm a little tentative to mess with it since all the tutorials I've seen assume that I'm using eth0.
5. All of the tutorials I've seen assume that I have a GUI running. I don't. How would I get the guest OS to blit to the video card (I have a video card, but Ubuntu Server just runs CLI)?
6. There are a lot of filesystems available for using `qemu-img`. Which should I use?

There are a lot of questions stuffed into this one. Sorry, but the question I care about most is at the beginning. My preference is to not to have to install Xen or use Virtual Box.

Comment: This is a great question and a lot of information. However, it doesn't fit the Q&A style for Ask Ubuntu. Could you please instead break your "answer" into a self answer below (everything after the break). That way you can later accept it as an answer and others can still provide answers or build upon your progress. [FAQ About self-answering](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to keep a running log of the progress that I've made so far. I'll clean this up later and post it as an answer if I succeed.

#### Day 1

1. I'm mainly [using this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-kvm-on-ubuntu-9.10). Note that it was originally for 9.10 /and/ it assumes that the primary network interface is eth0. I'm using a wireless card as my primary interface. As a sidenote, I'm not sure that using `libvirt` is the best way to go. We'll see.
2. It's true that bridging off a wireless card isn't supported out of the box. [Here is a howto](http://www.shanetomlinson.com/2009/bridging-a-wireless-card-in-kvmqemu/) on how to get around that (note that this howto builds off [another one](http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/bridge-wireless-cards/)). I've tried it but because I'm still trying to use `libvirt` to manage my VMs, I haven't verified that this workaround works.
3. With regard to what the flow of control looks like, tuxradar has [a pretty good article](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/howto-linux-and-windows-virtualization-kvm-and-qemu). Here's the diagram from that article: [image: Virtualization].

#### Day 2

1. I got my VM to boot. I ran `vmbuilder --debug --verbose` with [this as my config file](http://pastebin.com/k1VCs72E) in `/etc/vmbuilder.cfg`. I ran the most basic partition setup. Use google to see what to put in the `vmbuilder.partition` file. This takes a long time and I couldn't figure out how to install apt-proxy. If you can install apt-proxy, I would do it.
2. Still can't get networking to work. The guest OS can't see the host OS and vice versa.